# Customize Print Preview Dialog [DevExpress] Chart Control

Tags: charts, printing, devexpress

How can I customize the look and feel for the print dialog for charts 
bellow the code used to show the dialog and the snapshot

I need to control the bellow:
- hide/show icons
- change icon to my own icons
- Enable/Disable Icons
[image: print preview dialog]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer as bellow
DocumentPreviewControl

```html
<dxp:DocumentPreviewControl Name="PrintPreview">
            <dxp:DocumentPreviewControl.CommandProvider>
                <dxp:DocumentCommandProvider>
                    <dxp:DocumentCommandProvider.RibbonActions>

                        <!--Customize Action-->
                        <dxb:UpdateAction ElementName="{x:Static dxpbars:DefaultPreviewBarItemNames.Print}" 
                                    Property="{x:Static dxb:BarItem.LargeGlyphProperty}" 
                                   Value="{dx:QualifiedImage Uri=../../../Images/Export.png}" />
                        <!--Remove Action-->
                        <!--<dxb:RemoveAction ElementName="{x:Static dxpbars:DefaultPreviewBarItemNames.FileGroup}"/>-->

                        <!--Add New Action-->
                    </dxp:DocumentCommandProvider.RibbonActions>
                </dxp:DocumentCommandProvider>
            </dxp:DocumentPreviewControl.CommandProvider>
        </dxp:DocumentPreviewControl>
```